# Resizing screenshots/screen captures for inclusion in Beamer

Tags: image-processing, latex, imagemagick, beamer, gimp

Sorry, this may or may not be a programming question directly, but I am trying to resize screenshots with Imagemagick and Gimp to include in a Beamer presentation, but it comes out even blurrier than the [resizing done by LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024015/beamer-includegraphics-with-screenshots).

For instance, in Beamer I might have a command to rescale the image `\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{fig.png}`. Using something like

```
\begin{frame}
\message{width = \the\textwidth}
\message{height = \the\textheight}
\end{frame}
```

I have gotten the `\textwidth` and `\textheight` parameters in points (345.69548, 261.92444). So I have a script (in Python) that sends a system call to Imagemagick:

```
'convert %s -resize %.6f@ resized_%s' % (f,a,f)
```

where `a` is calculated as `\textwidth*\textheight*0.5**2` and `f` is the file name. When I then go back into my Beamer presentation and include the resized figure, `\includegraphics{resized_fig.png}`, the size looks approximately correct but it's super-blurry. I also tried resizing in Gimp (using the GUI) but no luck either... help? Thanks...

Comment: Maybe the blurriness changes with small adjustments to the resize value?

Comment: what resize algorithm are you using? and why don't you just scale using latex? what's wrong with that?

Comment: Yeah, it comes out blurry when rescaling with LaTeX - according to the other post on SO regarding this issue, it was recommended that other programs be used to resize. In imagemagick I am using the default resizing algorithm...
And regarding the blurriness changes with small adjustments, that didn't seem to work either -

Comment: If you're using pdflatex, the image is not scaled by LaTeX at all, it's just included in the PDF as-is. If it looks crappy, maybe try another viewer? Adobe Reader, in spite of all its flaws, does a good job at image scaling.

Comment: Oh, I see - yes, Adobe Reader is definitely better than Preview... but I guess all depends on whether their scaling is better than what I can do a priori...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to preserve pixel sharpness, i.e. do not scale and interpolate pixels, but represent them as small squares, I suggest this approach:

1. Convert you PNG image to EPS/PDF with [sam2p](https://pts.50.hu/sam2p/).
2. Include converted EPS or PDF in your document as usual. Every pixel will be just a small rectangular box, it will look crisp and sharp, and will scale without interpolation.

For example, let's assume we have a small raster image, that we want to show:

[image: 10×10]

We can convert it to vector PDF with this command:

```
sam2p 10x10.png PDF: 10x10.pdf
```

Now as we have a vector version (where every pixel is a rectangular), we can include it in whatever LaTeX document and scale freely. All pixels will scale, but will not be interpolated.

For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={4cm,4cm},margin=2pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{10x10.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This will look like this:

[image: 10×10 scaled without interpolation]

Drawbacks:

- PDF version of the image is likely to be several times bigger than its original PNG version.